# Tensorflow program give different answers after deployed on aws lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, session, tensorflow, aws-lambda

I have wrote a program with Tensorflow that identifies a number of figures in an image. The model is trained with a function and then used with another function to label the figures. The training have been done on my computer and the resulting model upload to aws with the solve function.

I my computer it works well, but when create a lambda in aws it works strange and start giving different answers with the same test data.

The model in the solve function is this:

```
# Recreate neural network from model file generated during training
# input
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, size_of_image])
# weights
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([size_of_image, num_chars]))
# biases
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([num_chars]))
```

The solve function code to label the figures is this:

```
for testi in range(captcha_letters_num):

    # load model from file
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(model_path + '.meta',
                                       clear_devices=True)
    saver.restore(sess, model_path)

    # Data to label
    test_x = np.asarray(char_imgs[testi], dtype=np.float32)

    predict_op = model(test_x, W, b)

    op = sess.run(predict_op, feed_dict={x: test_x})

    # find max probability from the probability distribution returned by softmax
    max_probability = op[0][0]
    max_probability_index = -1

    for i in range(num_chars):
        if op[0][i] > max_probability:
            max_probability = op[0][i]
            max_probability_index = i

    # append it to final output
    final_text += char_map_list[max_probability_index]

    # Reset the model so it can be used again
    tf.reset_default_graph()
```

With the same test data it gives different answers, don't know why.

Comment: Oh no! It has become self-aware!

Comment: @dashmug hahahah

Comment: Where do you create your `tf.Session` in that program? I'd suggest moving the `saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(...)`, `saver.restore(...)`, and `sess = tf.Session()` outside the `for testi in range(captcha_letters_num):` loop, to see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

What I finally do was to keep the Session outside the loop and initialize the variables. After ending the loop, reset the graph.

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()

sess = tf.Session()

# Initialize variables
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

.
.
.

# passing each of the 5 characters through the NNet
for testi in range(captcha_letters_num):

    # Data to label
    test_x = np.asarray(char_imgs[testi], dtype=np.float32)

    predict_op = model(test_x, W, b)

    op = sess.run(predict_op, feed_dict={x: test_x})

    # find max probability from the probability distribution returned by softmax
    max_probability = op[0][0]
    max_probability_index = -1

    for i in range(num_chars):
        if op[0][i] > max_probability:
            max_probability = op[0][i]
            max_probability_index = i

    # append it to final output
    final_text += char_map_list[max_probability_index]

# Reset the model so it can be used again
tf.reset_default_graph()

sess.close()
```